# Using named arguments with Application.Run (or equiv)

Tags: ms-access, vba, eval

I'm attempting to pass arguments to a VBA function via a string (user input from form)

The following code is throwing Runtime Error 2517 (Access cannot find the procedure '.') after it finishes running function `a`

```
Public Function a(Optional al As Boolean, Optional bl As Boolean)
    Debug.Print al
End Function

Public Sub b()
    Application.Run a, "bl:=false, al:=false"
End Sub
```

The correct syntax for the function would be `Application.Run "a", "false", "false"` but this approach cannot handle named arguments (which is a must for me)

I tried using the `eval()` function but it cannot resolve the named arguments.

Any suggestions on runtime error or any way in which I can pass a string with named arguments (as above) to a VBA function?

Answer (score 0):

A is a function, functions return results
try
make it a procedure and just call it
forget using application.run